# Need help to understand how missing values increases after mice imputation

Tags: r, r-mice

I had a dataset with 52 variables and lot of NA. I used mice imputation to impute missing values. After mice imputation all the variables imputed except one variable which has 49 missing values originally increased to 259 missing values. Any idea how to solve this

My code as below

```
library(mice)
miceMod <- mice(FRAtrain[, !names(FRAtrain) %in% "medv"], method="rf")  
miceOutput <- complete(miceMod)
summary(miceOutput)
FRAtrain = miceOutput
anyNA(FRAtrain)
```

Missing value before mice imputation

```
 Sales              Income.from.financial.services 
   46                                         176
```

Missing value after imputation

```
 Sales              Income.from.financial.services 
 259                                           0
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataset that allows us to reproduce the error? I don't have this error using other datasets